# How to write a better Regex with OR patterns in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex which should validate a value which

1. can be a 3 digit number OR
2. can be a 4 digit number but the first digit should be 0 OR
3. can be a alpha numeric value with length 5

I did this regex which seems to working but I believe there is a better way of writing this. This is my regex. Please suggest a better way

```
(^[0-9]{3}$)|(^0[0-9]{3}$)|(^[0-9a-zA-Z]{5}$)
```

Comment: You said "alpha numeric value with length 5" but your regex only allows numbers?

Comment: Corrected it now :)

Answer (score 4):

Using an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `0` can make it shorter and also change to the alphanumeric in the end:

```
/^(?:0?\d{3}|[a-z\d]{5})$/i
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/K7InMy/1) (pattern is already in delimiters with [`i` flag](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction) for *ignoring case*)

Answer (score 0):

here is one way about it

```
/^(0?\d{3}|[\D\d]{5})/
```

https://regex101.com/r/s8Swc0/1